# Doctrine / Symfony - force valid entity state

Tags: php, symfony, validation, doctrine-orm

I am creating my first bigger project using doctrine, which by now, I love and hate !

The thing that I don't get about it is this:
Why is it totally OK for an entity to be in an invalid state ?

I mean, of course, you can use a validator to check if the entity is valid ( e.g before  persistence ), but wouldn't it be so much better if it was just not possible to even be in an invalid state ?

```
class Author
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    public $name;
}
```

IMHO it should not be possible to do:

```
$author = new Author();
```

as this results in an entity that is not valid.
Yes, you could do this:

```
class Author
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @var string
     */
    public $name;

    public function __construct( string  $name )
    {
        $this->setName($name);
    }


    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function setName(string $name)
    {
        if($name ==''){
            throw new \Exception('name must be set');
        }        
        $this->name = $name;
    }

}
```

But then, what is the assertion good for, right ?

So, am I missing something here, or is this just the way it is ?

Comment: to be clear, this has nothing to do with form validation

Comment: Valid state? What is valid state? When this state should be checked?

Comment: In this case, the entity is only valid if the name is not blank ( @Assert\NotBlank ), no ?

Comment: __What__ and more important __when__ will check the entity? Every time entity changed?

Comment: No, actually BEFORE change, as the "change" should be refused if the entity would be in an invalid state after the changes.

Comment: So, how do you expect to check `$author->setName('')`? What if you have 20 authors in script? __Something__ should check these entities and in the end you don't persist them to database. What's the point then?

Comment: Well, in my example I do, as there is a check before setting the property, but this is not making any use of the validator component of Symfony. So it can be done ..

Comment: IMHO it should not matter if a entity was persisted or not to be sure that it is in a valid state.

Answer (score 1):

Oh god. I've talked about it. Too bad it was [in french](http://talks.nekland.fr/Doctrine/)!

Nevermind, I strongly agree with you and see nothing wrong in throwing exceptions if your input data is not good in the entity.

Besides, to me Doctrine has no limitation on this kind of usage. Actually anemic models were documented in the official Doctrine documentation. So yes, it's not obvious that Doctrine support non-anemic model. But thanks to [awesome contributors](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/pull/6902), times change.

I'd like to "resolve" your problem but I don't see any. I hope I gave what you expected.